# Regular Expression: pull part from string. with JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey all im not every good with regexp i was hoping someone could help.

ok so this is the sting "KEY FOUND! [ 57:09:91:40:32:11:00:77:16:80:34:40:91 ]"

And i need to pull "57:09:91:40:32:11:00:77:16:80:34:40:91", now this key can be meany length not just as written here and with or with out the ":"

now the second sting i would like to test and extract is: "[00:00:09] Tested 853 keys (got 179387 IVs)", i would like to pull "00:00:09" and "853" and "179387".

this would be the raw string  http://regexr.com?31pcu or http://pastebin.com/eRbnwqn7

this is what im doing now.

```
var pass = new RegExp('KEY FOUND\!')
var tested = new RegExp('Tested')
var fail = new RegExp('\Failed. Next try with ([0-9]+) IVs')
var data="Look at the link i added"
if (tested.test(data)) {
self.emit('update', mac, {
    'keys' : data.split('Tested ')[1].split(' keys ')[0],
    'ivs' : data.split('got ')[1].split(' IVs')[0]
});
} else if (pass.test(data)) {
var key = data.split('KEY FOUND! [')[1].split(' ]')[0].split(':').join('');

} else if (fail.test(data)) {
console.log(data);
}
```

thanks all

Edit:
I have added more the the question to help with the answer

Comment: I have added the raw sting that would come up. Sorry about that.

Comment: This question is still not clear what the range of input is and what the exact output you want is.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have updated my question so you can see how im doing it and what i want from the sting.

Comment: aircrack... I'm not helping you with any of that rubbish

Answer (score 0):

If it is always surrounded by `[]` then it is simple:

`\[([\s\S]*)\]`

This will match any characters enclosed by `[]`.

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?31pcl).